# ¿Que significa (string)$max != 'INF'?

Tags: php

¿Alguien  me ayuda a comprender esto?

Me encontraba practicando con PHP, me topé con este código. Estoy tratando de resolverlo:

```
function float_max( $mul = 2, $affine = 1 ) {
    $max  = 1;
    $omax = 0;

    while( (string) $max != 'INF' ) { 
        $omax = $max; 
        $max *= $mul; 
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < $affine; $i++) {
        $pmax = 1; 
        $max = $omax;

        while( (string) $max != 'INF' ) {
            $omax  = $max;
            $max  += $pmax;
            $pmax *= $mul;
        }
    }


    return $omax;
}

echo float_max();
```

No sé qué es lo que hace esta línea de código:

```
(string)$max != 'INF'
```

Cuando mando a imprimir `echo float_max();` de resultado obtengo `1.7976931348623E+308`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(string)$max != 'INF'` es un expresión de comparación. Compara si dos valores son diferentes.

En primer lugar tenemos: `(string)$max` que hace una conversión a tipo ***string*** del valor contenido en la variable `$max`.

En segundo lugar ***INF*** es una constante definida de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/math.constants.php.

Lo que no se es porque ***INF*** va entre comillas. En este caso es sólo un string... ¿una mala implementación?

Answer (score 3):

La [fuente de tu código es una contribución hecha en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.float.php#98216) hace hoy 8 años. Aparece en la parte del Manual que explica los [números de punto flotante](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.float.php).

El autor de la misma explica lo siguiente:

> En algunos casos es posible que desee obtener el valor máximo de un
>   flotante sin obtener "`INF`".
>
> `var_dump (1.8e308);` Generalmente mostrará: `float (INF)`
>
> Escribí una pequeña función que iterará para encontrar el mayor valor
>   de flotante no-infinito. Viene con un multiplicador configurable y
>   valores afines para que pueda compartir más CPU para obtener una
>   estimación más precisa.
>
> No he visto mejores valores con más afines, pero bueno, la posibilidad
>   está aquí, así que si realmente lo que vale la pena es el tiempo de la
>   CPU, sólo trate de afinarla más.
>
> Los mejores resultados parecen ser con `mul=2/affine=1`. Puedes jugar
>   con los valores y ver lo que obtienes. Lo bueno es que este método
>   funcionará en cualquier sistema.

Esta es la función original... creo que es prácticamente el mismo código de tu pregunta:

```
<?php
  function float_max($mul = 2, $affine = 1) {
    $max = 1; $omax = 0;
    while((string)$max != 'INF') { $omax = $max; $max *= $mul; }

    for($i = 0; $i < $affine; $i++) {
      $pmax = 1; $max = $omax;
      while((string)$max != 'INF') {
        $omax = $max;
        $max += $pmax;
        $pmax *= $mul;
      }
    }
    return $omax;
  }
?>
```

---

Por lo que explica el mismo autor:

- Es evidente que aquí `'INF'`hace referencia la [constante `INF` de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/math.constants.php), la cual representa **Infinito**.
- `(string) $max` hace una [conversión de tipo](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion), convirtiendo la variable `$max` a una cadena de caracteres.
- `!=` es un [operador de comparación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php), que devolverá `TRUE` si los valores comparados son **diferentes** después de la manipulación de tipos.

---

Lo que hace en definitiva la línea de código:

```
while( (string) $max != 'INF' ) {  ...
```

Es lo siguiente:

1. Convertir `$max` a cadena
2. Entrar en un bucle mientras el valor de `$max` convertido a cadena sea diferente a un valor `INFINITO`.

¿Por qué escribe `'INF'` y no `INF`, tratándose de una constante? No estoy seguro, pero al parecer, cuando se trata de valores infinitos, lo que PHP devuelve es una cadena con este valor: **`INF`**. Eso es lo que parece explicarse [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-infinite.php), al decir:

> That will return true for any string ending with "INF".

Es **lógico**, tratándose de comparaciones. Porque infinito no es en realidad un valor ... ¿no? Lo único que puedes recibir es algún indicativo de que es infinito.

Comment: Si, de hecho es el mismo código! muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha ayudado a enterderlo mejor!

Answer (score 0):

> La función que tienes es para encontrar el mayor número en coma flotante soportado por la CPU que utilices.

**INF** es una constante de PHP que representa el infinito.

Fuente: [enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/math.constants.php)

Answer (score 0):

Es una comparacion logica pero para poder realizarla es necesario convertir la variable de tipo`int` a `string`:

```
(string)$max
```

Despues el operador logico NOT `!=` para compararlo con la cadena de texto `'INF'`.

En caso de que el autor del codigo haya querido compararlo con la constante `INF` de PHP tuvo que haber quitado las comillas simples.

Entonces:

```
(string)$max != 'INF'
```

Sí la variable `$max` convertida a `string` es distinta (`!=`) de la otra `string` `'INF'` la condicion se cumplira.